Headless JS task in React Native JS not running even though called from Native service
I'm trying to call Headless task triggered by CallScreeningService by passing the incoming number to Headless.js which handles the data. It also triggered foreground service for my RN app.
The log from my CallScreeningService.kt and CallHeadlessService.kt is logged in logcat, which indicate its running. My foreground service is also running. But somehow the Headless.js is not running.
This is my CallScreeningService.kt
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
class CallScreeningService: CallScreeningService() {
    @SuppressLint("VisibleForTests")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    override fun onScreenCall(callDetails: Call.Details) {
        Log.d("Call_Receiver", "[SERVICE] Fetching caller number")
        val incomingNum = callDetails.handle.schemeSpecificPart
        Log.d("Call_Receiver", "[SERVICE] Incoming call from: $incomingNum")

        val intentForeground = Intent(this, CallForegroundService::class.java)
        startService(intentForeground)
        Log.d("Call_Receiver", "[FOREGROUND] Service called")

        val intent = Intent(this, CallHeadlessService::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("incomingNumber", incomingNum)
        this.startService(intent)

        HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(this)
        Log.d("Call_Receiver", "[MODULE] Headless task waking up")

        val response = CallResponse.Builder()
            .setDisallowCall(false)
            .setSilenceCall(false)
            .build()

        respondToCall(callDetails, response)
    }
}

This is my CallHeadlessService.kt
package com.dev.justcall

import android.content.Intent
import android.util.Log
import com.facebook.react.HeadlessJsTaskService
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap
import com.facebook.react.jstasks.HeadlessJsTaskConfig

class CallHeadlessService : HeadlessJsTaskService() {
    override fun getTaskConfig(intent: Intent?): HeadlessJsTaskConfig {
        Log.d("Call_Receiver", "[HEADLESS] Task called")
        val incomingNumber = intent?.getStringExtra("incomingNumber") ?: ""
        Log.d("Call_Receiver", "[HEADLESS] Incoming Number: $incomingNumber")
        val taskData: WritableMap = Arguments.createMap()
        taskData.putString("incomingNumber", incomingNumber)
        Log.d("Call_Receiver", "[HEADLESS] Task Data: $taskData")

        return HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
            "IncomingCallTask",
            taskData,
            0,
            true
        )
    }
}

This is my Headless.js
import { AppRegistry, NativeModules } from "react-native";

//Import Javascript components
import CallerID from "./CallerID";
import CleanPhoneNumber from "./CleanPhoneNumber";
import StartPage from "../../app";
import { name as appName } from '../../app.json';

const { CallNativeModule } = NativeModules;

const handleIncomingCallTask = async (taskData) => {
    const { incomingNumber } = taskData;

    console.log('[HEADLESS] Task received incoming number:', incomingNumber);

    //Get wallet connection status and provider
    const { walletSigner } = global.appData;

    if (walletSigner) {
        console.log('[HEADLESS] User logged in');
        try {
            const cleanedPhoneNumber = await CleanPhoneNumber(incomingNumber);
    
            const profile = await CallerID(cleanedPhoneNumber, walletSigner);
    
            const name = profile[0];
            CallNativeModule.receiveCallerID(name, cleanedPhoneNumber);
            console.log('[HEADLESS] Caller ID sent to Native Module');
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.message.includes('[HEADLESS] Invalid phone number length.')) {
                console.log('[HEADLESS] Invalid phone number length.');
            } else if (error.message.includes('[HEADLESS] Phone number is not registered')) {
                console.log('[HEADLESS] Phone number is not registered.');
            } else {
                console.log('[HEADLESS] Error:', error);
            };
        };
    } else {
        console.log('[HEADLESS] User not logged in');
    };
};

console.log('[HEADLESS] App starting...');
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => StartPage);
AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('IncomingCallTask', () => handleIncomingCallTask);

This is my CallForegroundService.kt
package com.dev.justcall

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Build
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat

class CallForegroundService : Service() {
    private val channelID = "CallServiceChannel"


    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Log.d("Call_Receiver", "[FOREGROUND] Setting up")

        createNotificationChannel()

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelID)
            .setContentTitle("Call Service")
            .setContentText("JustCall is active")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .build()

        startForeground(1, notification)
        Log.d("Call_Receiver", "[FOREGROUND] Service started")

        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
                channelID,
                "Caller ID Active",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            )
            val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
            Log.d("Call_Receiver", "[FOREGROUND] Notification channel created")
        }
    }
}

The problem only occur when running foreground service. The headless task ran perfectly when the RN app is opened.
I suspect it was the delay time between foreground service starting and calling the headless task. But it wasn't the case.
I was hoping to be able to run the headless task in foreground when the app was not running initially. Basically the CallScreening trigger the foreground service to start the app.

In order to start foreground service you need to run startForeground with active notification. startService will not works for the foreground task running in the background since api >=26. You can read more about foreground service in the android docs https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/foreground-services
Here's example of the android service used in react native to start a foreground service with the active notification.
class SomeForegroundService : Service() {

    private val SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345
    private val CHANNEL_ID = "SOMENAME"


    private val handler: Handler = Handler()
    private val runnableCode: Runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            val context = applicationContext
            val service = Intent(context, CallHeadlessService::class.java)
            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putString("foo", "bar")
            service.putExtras(bundle)
            context.startService(service)
            HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context)
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000)

        }
    }
    
    companion object {
            var isRunning = false
        }
    
        private fun createNotificationChannel() {
            // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
            // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
                val channel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Foreground Service Channel", importance)
                channel.description = "CHANNEL DESCRIPTION"
                val notificationManager = getSystemService(
                    NotificationManager::class.java
                )
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
            }
        }
    
        override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    
            handler.post(runnableCode)
    
            isRunning = true
    
            createNotificationChannel()
            val notificationIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                0,
                notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            )
    
           
            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(this.resources.getIdentifier("launcher_icon", "mipmap", this.packageName))
                .setContentTitle("Some title")
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .build()
    
            startForeground(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
            return START_STICKY
        }
    
        override fun onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy()
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnableCode)
            isRunning = false;
        }


    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

}


I already have CallForegroundService.kt which runs startForeground(). I have added it in the original question.
Although I did try and follow your code, but Headless.js is still not running.
